# ActiveRecord: how to throw exception when reference key not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

For example, I have two models:

```
class CheckInDetail < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
end
```

For example, when I insert `CheckInDetail`, I add foreign key `product_id` to hash params. I tried use some non-exist product id and column `product_id` will be null. I want to throw exception when inserting like this.

There is a way that use `validate` on model for checking that field before inserting. But I think this will cost time (because I insert bunch of items) and not really necessary because client doesn't do that. (just in case something really went wrong).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the benefits of relational databases, as you could add a foreign_key reference to your migration and everything should work perfectly.
You could run a migration with `rails g migration add_foreign_key_to_check_in_details`

in the migration, you should add something like:

```
class AddForeignKeyToCheckInDetails < AR::Migration
  def change
    remove_foreign_key :check_in_details, :products
    add_foreign_key :check_in_details, :products, dependent: :delete
  end
end
```

With this in place all attempts to save a non existent product will fail. Also ensure to add a NOT NULL constraint to your `product_id` column, as attemts to save a check_in_detail with a null product_id will succeed. The update to the migration would look like:

```
change_column :check_in_details, :product_id, :integer, null: false
```

Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: both? You mean to change the column and add_reference. Yes adding the reference can work, but doesn't prevent a submission with a `nil` product_id.

Comment: ah. I understand. thanks so much with your kind explanation :D